# Spring cloud config server accessing GIT repository using SSH key giving Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

Tags: spring, git, authentication, ssh, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to set up Spring cloud config server and would like to access GIT repository using SSH keys. I have created SSH public and private keys using `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "PIQ-Config"` command and added the key on GIT SSH public keys.

[image: SSH key configuration on GIT repo]

I am able to git clone from command line using ssh git clone command.

Below are the configuration in STS

```
server:
        git:
          uri: https://visualstudio.com/p2020/_git/myrepo
          ignoreLocalSshSettings: true
          hostKey: mypublickey
          hostKeyAlgorithm: ssh-rsa
          privateKey: |
                      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

My server gets started properly without any error. But when i am trying to hit the URL on console it is giving below error

**Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered**

Please help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using https not ssh, so you need username and password authentication not private key

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30587193)